# How to grant intent receiver the same permissions as intent sender?

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I'm going to send email using standard android intent `ACTION_SEND`. The problem is that i'm trying to attach file (`emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(..))`) which is stored in my app cache and email app does not have permissions to read it as it's another package name. I don't want to save the file in public available storage like external storage (sd). How can i grant intent receiver the same permissions as sender activity?

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass a simple file:// url as returned by Uri.fromFile(...)

Instead you need use [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

> FileProvider is a special subclass of ContentProvider that facilitates secure sharing of files associated with an app by creating a content:// Uri for a file instead of a file:/// Uri.

If that doesn't go far enough for you, also take a look at [CWAC-Provider](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) from CommonsWare

> CWAC-Provider: Helping to Make Content Providers Sane.
>
> This project offers a StreamProvider, based on Google's FileProvider. Like FileProvider, StreamProvider is designed to serve up files, for reading and writing, through the ContentProvider interface (content:// Uri values). StreamProvider offers:
>
> - Serving files from assets and raw resources
> - Serving files from getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalCacheDir()
>
> in addition to FileProvider's support for serving files from getFilesDir(), getCacheDir(), and Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().